# Rename multiple values of a variable into the same category within a new variable in R

Tags: r

I need to rename multiple values of a variable into categories within a new variable in R. Is there a more efficient way to do this rather than rename every single one individually? Here is the code I have so far

```
data.set %>% mutate(income = recode(country, "USA" = "HIC", "Canada" = "HIC", "Japan" = "HIC", "India" = "LMIC"))
```

Currently the data looks like this, and I want to create the income variable

```
ID           countries        **income**
1            USA                 HIC
2            Canada              HIC
3            Japan               HIC
4            USA                 HIC
5            India               LMIC
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by is there a more efficient way. Alternatively, you can make a second dataframe and `left_join` them together by the countries column. Also, your data says countries while your function says country, maybe that is the source of the error.

Comment: To clarify, is there some function that would allow me to do "HIC" = "USA", "Japan", "Canada" instead of typing out "HIC" = "USA", "HIC = "Japan", "HIC" = Canada"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recode is a simpler version of case_when, so we can just use case_when.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(income = case_when(
    countries %in% c("USA", "Canada", "Japan") ~ "HIC",
    countries %in% c("India") ~ "LMIC",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))
```